# Bug with the dmbl designer file under VS2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, linq, datacontext

I had been struggling today with the linq2sql dbml design files. When I start out and place my tables on the designer everything is OK. Them I modify the namespaces and turn off the connection string properties for the data context. Then I want to create partial extensions of my linq entities. So I hit F7 on the files designer. At this point everything is cool too. Then when I change something with the DB's schema I go back and add another table or delete and re-add an old one, the MyContext.dbml loses the MyContext.design file underneath it. The other 2 (the .cs and the .layout are still there). Naturally it breaks everything I need to start from scratch. Very annoying. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you edit the .designer file? That is a big no-no; that ist your file to edit (there should be a big warning at the top).

Comment: @Marc, no never edit the generated data context files. I create stand alone partial classes to handle extended stuff.

Comment: now I remember! Sorry I was less alert on the 15th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! Yes! You're using VS2008, right?

This is a known bug, and it actually matters where your `using` directives are in **your** half of the `partial` class...

```
using Foo;
namespace Bar {
    // ...
}
```

is bad, and trashes the designer file...

```
namespace Bar {
    using Foo;
    // ...
}
```

is fine!

This **only** applies when you have `SomeName.dbml` and `SomeName.cs`, so another fix is to rename the file. This is fixed in VS2010. Crazy, huh?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your classes in separate file/files. C# compiler doesn't care where parts are so this is a simple workaround.

Besides if you wrote your classes to the generated file(it isn't very clear in your post) then this is not a bug, but a desired behaviour.